# How to use string in file.WriteLine

Tags: vb.net, windows

I'm trying to insert a string of code into a text file with `file.WriteLine` in Visual Basic, but whenever I check the text file it only copied the string name, not it's content, here's my code:

The text file will have the "printf(strc011);" instead of replacing the "strc011" part with "Hello World!"

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("TEST.txt", True)
        Dim strc011 As String
        strc011 = "Hello World!"
        file.WriteLine("#include<stdio.h>
                        main()
                        {
                        printf(strc011);}
        ")
        file.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So this is not really Basic, it's Virtual Basic? Joking aside, why tag this with C# and VBA instead of VB.Net?

Comment: And why would you assume that the `strc011` value would magically get injected into the output here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using [VB 14 or newer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx#code-snippet-10), you'll want to use [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx), a type of templating.

Here's a correct implementation:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("TEST.txt", True)
        Dim strc011 As String
        strc011 = "Hello World!"
        file.WriteLine($"#include<stdio.h>
                        main()
                        {
                        printf({strc011});}
        ")
        file.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, turns out I defined & called the string the wrong way, here's the working code:

`Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("TEST.txt", True)
        Dim strc011 As String = "Hello World!"
        file.WriteLine("#include<stdio.h>
                        main()
                        {
                        printf(""" & strc011 & """);}
        ")
        file.Close()
    End Sub
End Class`

Dim strc011 As String = "Hello World!" ***- for defining the string***

""" & strc011 & """ ***- for calling it***